# Bitcoin Cash "Cash Address" format

Tags: address, bitcoin-cash

What is "Cash Address" or "CashAddr"? Is that a new Bitcoin Cash address format?

Answer (score 14):

"CashAddr" is the name of the new Bitcoin Cash address format, which is heavily influenced by SegWit Bech32 format.

It looks like this:

```
bitcoincash:qpm2qsznhks23z7629mms6s4cwef74vcwvy22gdx6a
```

The format is consisting of a prefix (`bitcoincash`, `bchtest` or `bchreg`), a seperator (always `:`), and a 42 character payload.

TIP: P2PKH starts with `q` while P2SH starts with `p`

Currently it's compatible with all Bitcoin Cash wallets and services except a few.

The address format can be converted to the old format using [cashaddr.bitcoincash.org](https://cashaddr.bitcoincash.org/) if your wallet is not compatible.

Comment: How is this different from ecash addresses? cashaddr.bitcoincash.org failed to parse qpvefcwykgraq5p4yh55xup0lkpqkve02g3lmsjvw6    cash address.

Comment: @VincentAlex Look out with e-cash there supply is 21 trillion. You have been warned.